# Inactivity, disconnecting from the service Android Kotlin Error

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello automatically kicks from the application after a certain time.

And it gives this error "Inactivity, disconnecting from the service"

How can i solve this problem?

I made changes in the code part but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: Post context and code for understanding the problem.

Comment: `Inactivity, disconnecting from the service` is not a message you should be concerned about. You'll find it in Android Studio's console when your app's process is idle.

Comment: However, if your app crashes, something else is responsible for it. Please check a few lines above `Inactivity, disconnecting from the service` in the logcat (not the run tab) to see the actual report of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete application from phone/emulator in development (uninstall)
2. Click File > Invalid Caches / Restart... in the upper left corner of Android Studio

Then you would see that the error message doesn't come up as the Android studio turns off and restarts.